# How to save a gganimate plot as mp4 file with high quality?

Tags: r, mp4, gganimate

I would like to save my animated graphic made by the `gganimate' package in high quality mp4, but the best I can do is save it in low quality. Does anyone have a solution?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(geobr)
library(gganimate)
library(av)

brasilm <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = brasil, fill = "black", color = "yellow", size=.15)

map <- brasilm +
  geom_point(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude,colour=riscofogo),
             data = fc, size = 0.2,
             alpha = .5) +
  labs(title="Focos de Calor no Cerrado em 2020", subtitle = "Data: {frame_time}", size = "Users") +
  transition_time(y) +
  ease_aes("linear")+
  scale_color_gradient("Risco de Fogo\n", low = "yellow", high = "red")+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  theme_minimal()


b <- animate(map, fps=5, renderer = av_renderer())

anim_save("focos2020.mp4", b)
```

Comment: I don't know where the `brasil` data comes from so this isn't reproducible for me. I suggest using a standard gganimate example in your question if the specific animation isn't important to your concern.

Comment: Jon, I started from a dataset of hot spots, made a map of points and then animated it by gganimate. When saved this way in mp4, the video quality appears to be low. But it is a common gganimate chart. I don't know how to post a video here, but I'll try to post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you configure width and height could improve quality, for example:

```
b <- animate(map, width = 1525, height = 972, fps=5, renderer = av_renderer())
```

Comment: Hi User_Fabio, welcome to SO. The thing that makes SO such a valuable resource is the focus on questions that are [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) and answers that can be proven to solve the question at hand. While your answer _might_ solve this issue, there is no way to verify it as the OP did not provide enough information. Please familiarise yourself with [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: Thank you L Tyrone. I've had this problem before and the suggestion worked for me. I could not reproduce the example with Igor Cobelo's data but I suggest that he try it and tell us if it meets his expectations.